# A phrase to mean "an acceptable deal"

Tags: phrase-requests

I need a phrase that indicates the speaker find a bargain acceptable, but not particularly favorable.  The natural expression, in American English, would be "I can live with it" but for reasons too complicated to explain, I cannot use the word "live" or any variation on it.

**Edit:** People asked for more detail.  I'm writing a story in which one character makes a bargain in which he might very well die.  He's trying to explain why he accepted the deal.  I don't want to write, "I can live with it" — since literally he cannot — and anything that implies acceptance *over time* is wrong.  If he doesn't die, then it's a great deal, so if he lives long enough to "come to terms with it" or "tolerate it", there'll be nothing to tolerate or come to terms with.  I'm looking for a pithy phrase meaning "it's the best deal I could do and it was better than nothing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

- "It's satisfactory." ([The definition of satisfactory being:](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=satisfactory&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=lvSmT7KiEeKI6QHa8YmtBA&ved=0CGgQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3f36ec44d8ae71d8&biw=1267&bih=607) 1.Fulfilling expectations or needs; acceptable, though not outstanding or perfect.)
- "I will get used to it." (The implication being it's done, but I'm not happy about it.)
- "I'm not quite happy about it." (Again, it's done, but I'm not 100% happy about it.)

Comment: ["Satisfactory"](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/000/554/facepalm.jpg).  Jeez, I'v been hunting that word for three days.  @JLG -- when my novel comes out, I'll sent you a free e-copy.

Comment: @Malvolio, it's your story, so use whatever word you want, but to my ear "satisfactory" does _not_ suggest that the deal is "not particularly favorable", only that it is less than perfect.  At the end of a negotiation both parties should feel the deal is _satisfactory_.

Answer (score 3):

***Workable***, depending on your context and phrasing, can carry a connotation of "less than optimal".

Answer (score 2):

Still a bit hard to pin down with the context given, but I offer *It is good enough* or *It is the best I could do* or *It is tolerable*.

Answer (score 0):

Most fair deals end up with both parties feeling a little pain.

How about something like:

> ***I've come to terms with it.***

Comment: Ooh, that would be good... except, the reason that I don't want to use the word "live" is that the negotiation of the deal in question involves risks to the *life* of the speaker -- and I don't want to repeat the word "live" in a different sense.  Similarly, they were just talking about the *terms* of the agreement, so I don't want to use the word "terms" in a different sense.  (I feel like the guy in *Throw Momma From The Train* trying to come up with a word for "hot and moist".  Spoiler alert: Momma makes the winning suggestion, "sultry".)

Comment: @Malvolio, if you want something more specific, I suggest you post some more specific context. This will make it much easier to give relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

Say: "This is good! Although not the best."
or: "We're almost there."  / "Close, but not close enough to close the deal?"

Comment: Thanks, but the deal's been closed, the speaker is trying to explain why he agreed.  Think "not unacceptable".

Answer (score 0):

How about these:

> Bearable, endurable, barely acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

To throw in another suggestion, you could say that the deal was *mediocre*, with the main definition of *mediocre* being "of only ordinary or moderate quality; neither good nor bad; barely adequate".